# Cannot access the setting

Tags: nvidia, login, login-screen, settings

I cannot access the setting in Ubuntu. Whenever I want to go to the setting by any method, Ubuntu would automatically collapse and go to the login page. After I log into the system later, the screen is just like when I first turn it on and nothing I did before is stored.

I guess it may relate to my work did before: I fell into a login loop when I installed the ubuntu. It was caused by Nvidia Graphic issues and I fixed it by doing the steps illustrated in this answer: [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics/762607#762607)
. I just did steps 1-4 in section 3 and it works.

I am using ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall the settings again on your system by running :

"sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center"
in Terminal.

Comment: I tried, but it brings no improvement to my problem.